# Tooltip with shortened characters in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

The following `code` will:

1. Test to see if the characters in a `div` are more then ten chars long
2. Shorten the text to less than ten characters
3. Append `...` to the `div`
4. On hover, it will show and hide a `div` that is intended to show the full text

I edited this once I found one of the problems

so far it works with only the first div and no others

```
<html>

<head>

<title>limit chars 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {


      $("#div2").hide();

var elem = $("#div1");
var fn1 = function(){ $('#div2').show();};
var fn2 = function(){ $('#div2').hide();};


    if(elem){
        if (elem.text().length > 10)
         elem.text(elem.text().substr(0,12)


    )}

    if(elem){
    if (elem.text().length > 10) 
    elem.text(elem.append("...")
   )};





    if(elem){
    if (elem.text().length > 10) 
    //elem.text(elem.append("...")


  $(elem).mouseover(fn1).mouseout(fn2);



   };


//$(elem).mouseover(fn1).mouseout(fn2);

  });//end
</script>

<style>

#div2{color:blue; }

</style>




</head>


<body>

this is where the fun begins.
<div id="div1">
12345ebfkqbweub qiuweiu 
</div>
<div id="div2">full text in tooltip</div>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: "it tests ALL divs named #div1" - FYI, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. Results may not be consistent across browsers, and it definitely breaks the HTML specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning your event handlers in your `if (elem.text().length > 10)` block.

```
if(elem){
    if (elem.text().length > 10)
        elem.text(elem.text().substr(0,12));
        elem.mouseover(fn1).mouseout(fn2);
    }

    ...
```

To work on multiple `div`s, you would want to use the `jQuery.each` function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$( '.someclass' ).each( function( ) {
    // do your work in here, $(this) refers to the current element
} );
```

Comment: @namretiolnave If you put the `elem.mouseover(fn1).mouseout(fn2)` in that `if` block, it won't get executed if the text length is 10 or less. So rather than disabling the show/hide, you just never hook up that event to begin with.

Comment: if(elem){
    if (elem.text().length > 10) 
    //elem.text(elem.append("...")
  
  
  $(elem).mouseover(fn1).mouseout(fn2);


   };I have been trying to place "each in here and I know I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around this worked:thought I would share and make the world a better place:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //each iterates through all divs 



        $("div").each(function(){

        var $div = $(this);
        var $fC = $div.children("p:first-child");
        //show hide functions in vars
        var fn1 = function(){ $('#div2').show();};
        var fn2 = function(){ $('#div2').hide();};

    var loadedText="This is the full long name."

    //hide tooltip
        $("#div2").hide();

       ///conditional to ensure tooltip only shows up for shortened text and appdens only when >10
      if ($fC.text().length > 10) 
            {
                //alert("test");
                $fC.html($fC.html().substring(0,14));
                ($fC).append("[...]");
                //show hide
                ($fC).mouseover(fn1).mouseout(fn2);


            }


        //set tooltip position to follow mouse 
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          //$('#div2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
          $("#div2").css({ top : e.pageY + 5, left: e.pageX +5  }); 
           }); 




        //place content into div2

        //from another div class
        //$("#div2").text($(".foo").text());
        //from variable -content can be loaded there 
    $("#div2").text(loadedText)

        });//end each



    });//end main

    </script>
```